# Laravel collection: return only relationship and key

Tags: php, laravel, collections, pluck

I have a collection that resembles this:

```
$a = Model::with(['sub' => function($q) {
    $q->select('id', 'name')
}])->get();
```

This returns the following collection:

```
{
    0: {
        id: 0001,
        name: "item 1",
        type: "type a"
        'sub' [
            {
                'id': 10001,
                'name': "sub Item 1"
            },
            {
                'id': 10002,
                'name': "sub Item 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    1: {
        id: 0002,
        name: "item 2",
        type: "type a"
        'sub' [
            {
                'id': 11001,
                'name': "sub Item 4"
            },
            {
                'id': 11002,
                'name': "sub Item 5"
            }
        ]
    }
```

What I am trying to do is key the parent items by their ids and only return the relationship. For example

```
{
    0001: {
        'sub' [
            {
                'id': 10001,
                'name': "sub Item 1"
            },
            {
                'id': 10002,
                'name': "sub Item 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    0002: {
        'sub' [
            {
                'id': 11001,
                'name': "sub Item 4"
            },
            {
                'id': 11002,
                'name': "sub Item 5"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I cannot seem to get this to work. I have tried many variations including:

```
$a = Model::with(['sub' => function($q) {
    $q->select('id', 'name')
}])->pluck('sub', 'id');
```

This doesn't work as 'Pluck' is obviously looking for a a property of the parent model with the name of 'sub' which doesn't exit. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were almost there. You will need to do `->get()` before the `pluck()`.

```
$a = Model::with([
    'sub' => function ($q) {
        $q->select('id', 'name');
    },
])->get()->pluck('sub', 'id');
```

The `pluck()` used in your example will be the query builder version of `pluck` rather than the collection version.

Comment: This solution doesn't keep the key 'sub' in the results. However, in my actual situation, this isn't a problem. Thanks

Comment: @Typhoon101 What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

use `keyBy` to use your pk as array index.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-keyby

However ignoring other fields you probably would need `each` and `filter`. Wouldn't it be easier to select `Sub::where(...)` and then use collection `groupBy` on the parent_id: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby

So something like `Sub::where(...)->get()->groupBy('parent_id')`